# Find QR Factorization

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm self studying Linear Algebra and am having trouble with QR factorization. I want to find the QR factorization of Matrix A.

[image: This is the matrix A]

My attempt: I identified $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$ as the 3 column vectors of $A$ respectively.

I now want to find the orthonormal basis and have gotten $u_1 = [0\; 0\; 1\; 0]$, $u_2 = [0\; -1\; 0\; 0]$, $u_3 = 0$.

I think I have made a mistake here but am not sure what to do. I think $u_3$ should not be $0$ but cannot find a mistake in my calculations.

To get $u_3$, I calculated $v_3-(u_1 \cdot v_3)u_1 - (v_3 \cdot u_2)u_2$. Then, I divided it by $||u_3||$.

Comment: your u2 should be $[-1,0 , 0  ,0]^T$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $A$ is almost upper triangular, just the rows need to be rearranged.

Find a permutation matrix rearranges the rows from the order $1,2,3,4$ to
$3,1,4,2$. Then
$P A = \begin{bmatrix}  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} A=  R=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -3 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 4 \\  0 & 0 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}$.

If you let $Q=P^{-1} = P^T$ then you have the required factorisation.

Answer (score 0):

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&-3&0\\0&0&0\\2&0&0\\0&0&4\end{bmatrix}$$

According to your notation,

$$v_1=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\2\\0\end{bmatrix},v_2=\begin{bmatrix}-3\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},v_3=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\4\end{bmatrix}$$

We need to apply the Gram Schmidt orthonormalization process to find the $Q$ matrix.

---

$w_1=v_1=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}, ||w_1||=2 \implies u_1=\frac{w_1}{||w_1||}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

$w_2=v_2-(v_2.u_1)u_1=v_2-(0)u_1=\begin{bmatrix}-3\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}, ||w_2||=3 \implies u_2=\frac{w_2}{||w_2||}=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

$w_3=v_3-(v_3.u_1)u_1-(v_3.u_2)u_2=v_3-(0)u_1-(0)u_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\4\end{bmatrix}, ||w_3||=4 \implies u_3=\frac{w_3}{||w_3||}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Therefore, we can obtain our $Q$ matrix using $u_1,u_2,u_3$.

$$Q=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1&0\\0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

---

$R$ can be obtained using the following relation.

$$R=\begin{bmatrix}v_1.u_1&v_2.u_1&v_3.u_1\\
0&v_2.u_2&v_3.u_2\\
0&0&v_3.u_3\end{bmatrix}$$

---

$v_1.u_1=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}=2, v_2.u_1=\begin{bmatrix}-3\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}=0,
v_3.u_1=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\4\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}=0$

$v_2.u_2=\begin{bmatrix}-3\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}=3,
v_3.u_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\4\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}=0$

$v_3.u_3=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\4\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=4$

$\therefore$ $R=\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&4\end{bmatrix}$

$$\implies \begin{bmatrix}0&-3&0\\0&0&0\\2&0&0\\0&0&4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1&0\\0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&4\end{bmatrix}$$